# analyze table, optimize table, how often?

Tags: sql, mysql

in mysql i have 3 tables. one is 500,000, another 300,000, and finally around 5,000

they each get maybe 50-500 additional rows daily

should i run `analyze` and `optimize` table on them? if so then how often?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

optimize table rebuilds the table for InnoDB so it could take a wicked long time to run.  It's used for reclaiming space and recreating indexes.  I'd say run that rarely if at all.
[optimize table doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)

analyze should be redone whenever the overall  distribution of the indexed data changes significantly.  So if you're inserting the same type of stuff at the same rate over time - no need to run analyze often - do it maybe once a month.  But if things change drastically - such that you get way more of one type of data than another or something else unusual - then run it afterwards.

I run it for example after loading a new table with data and perhaps a good idea would be to run it against all like once a week if you have no clue.